# How do you get the Highlight color of a TDBGrid?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

For a read-only `TDBGrid` with a full row selection and default drawing disabled, I want to change the highlight color based on if the `TDBGrid` has focus.   When focused I just want the default, but `DrawCellHighlight()` is protected, so I need to set that color manually as well, the problem is `clHighlight` is not what it uses by default.  I like the color it uses but I don't know where you get it?

TIA!!

Comment: I had a quick glance at DrawCellHighlight in VCL.Grids.pas - seems like there is the answer.

Comment: Do you have theming enabled?

Comment: The `DrawingStyle` on the `TDBGrid` is `gdsThemed`

Comment: For now I just let default drawing happen then redraw if the grid doesn't have focus which works but double drawing just seems like wasted cpu time.

Answer (score 0):

The highlight color used by the TDBGrid when it has focus is determined by the clBtnFace system color. You can retrieve this color using the GetSysColor Windows API function with the COLOR_BTNFACE parameter. Here is an example of how you can use it:

```
uses
  Windows;

const
  COLOR_BTNFACE = 15; // The COLOR_BTNFACE system color index

procedure TForm1.MyDBGridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  HighlightColor: TColor;
begin
  // Set the highlight color based on whether the grid has focus or not
  if TDBGrid(Sender).Focused then
    HighlightColor := clHighlight // Use the default highlight color when focused
  else
    HighlightColor := GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE); // Use the system button face color otherwise

  // Draw the cell highlight
  if (gdSelected in State) then
  begin
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := HighlightColor;
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  end;

  // Draw the cell contents
  TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

Comment: `COLOR_BTNFACE` is already defined in the `Windows` unit, you don't need to redeclare it. But, you could just set the `HighlightColor` to `clBtnFace` instead of calling `GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE)` directly, the RTL will handle that system call for you when it is actually drawing with the `TColor`. Also, you say the highlight color when the grid **is** in focus is `clBtnFace`, but your code is using `clHighlight` (aka `GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT)`) instead, and then using `clBtnFace` when the grid **is not** in focus. A little inconsistent, don't you think? You should fix that.

Comment: For me, that's not the color used by default.  The `clHighlight` is darker blue (like system default).  The default it uses is a much lighter blue with black text.  `IsCustomStyleActive()` is true.